# C++ getline method not working

Tags: c++, encryption, cin

I'm sorry but I'm quite new to C++ but not programming in general. So I tried to make a simple encryption/decryption. However when I added the modification to my previous code (so there isn't two programs for encrypting and decrypting) I found that the code 'getline()' method no longer works. Instead it's just ignoring it when the code is ran. Here's the code:

```
int main(){
    std::string string;
    int op = 1; //Either Positive or Negative

    srand(256);
    std::cout << "Enter the operation: " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> op;
    std::cout << "Enter the string: " << std::endl;
    std::getline(std::cin, string); //This is the like that's ignored

    for(int i=0; i < string.length(); i++){
        string[i] += rand()*op; //If Positive will encrypt if negative then decrypt
    }
    std::cout << string << std::endl;

    std::getchar(); //A Pause 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm wondering what part is doing the decryption... It cannot be rand()*op, can it?

Comment: @owlstead Yes if op is negative then it'll do the opposite than the positive input.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because `std::cin >> op;` leaves a hanging `\n` in your code, and that's the first thing `getline` reads. Since `getline` stops reading as soon as it finds a newline character, the function returns immediately and doesn't read anything more. You need to ignore this character, for example, by using `cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');` ([`std::numeric_limits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) is defined in header `<limits>`), as stated on [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

Answer (score 4):

This is because you still have the newline character in the buffer which makes `getline()` stop reading as soon as it encounters it.

Use `cin.ignore()` to ignore the newline character from the buffer. This will do in your case.

In general, if you want to remove characters from your buffer untill a specific character, use:

```
cin.ignore ( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), ch )
```

Answer (score 3):

Use :

`cin.ignore ( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n' );`

to eat newlines from previous input `std::cin >> op;`

header - `<limits>`

Other way would be :

```
    while (std::getline(std::cin, str)) //don't use string
    if (str != "")
    {
       //Something good received

        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

As other stated already, the formatted input (using `in >> value`) start skipping space abd stop when they are done. Typically this results in leaving some whitespace around. When switching between formatted and unformatted input you typically want to get rid of leading space. Doing so can easily be done using the `std::ws` manipulator:

```
if (std::getline(std::cin >> std::ws, line)) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You must use `std::cin.ignore()` before `std::getline(std::cin, string)` to clear the buffer, because when you use `std::cin >> op` before the getline a `\n` gets in the buffer and `std::getline()` reads it. `std::getline()` takes only the line you type, when you skip a line, `std::getline()` closes, so when `std::getline()` picks up `\n` from the buffer it is already terminated before you type something, because `/n` skips a line.

Try this way:

```
int main(){
    std::string string;
    int op = 1; //Either Positive or Negative

    srand(256);
    std::cout << "Enter the operation: " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> op;
    std::cout << "Enter the string: " << std::endl;
    std::cin.ignore();
    std::getline(std::cin, string); //This is the like that's ignored

    for(int i=0; i < string.length(); i++){
        string[i] += rand()*op; //If Positive will encrypt if negative then decrypt
    }
    std::cout << string << std::endl;

    std::getchar(); //A Pause 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What value does your answer add over the other answers?