# getline() not working as intended

Tags: c++, string, getline

Hi I am having an unknown issue with getline(). My program is supposed to cout a prompt and then getline() should read in the user input but for some reason every time I run it just couts the prompt and skips to the next prompt, not allowing for me to input anything. I'll post the code and hopefully you guys can offer some advice.

```
int main()
{
    int students = 0;
    students = getStudents(students);

    int quizzes = 0;
    quizzes = getQuizzes(quizzes);

    string studentArray[50];
    int* quizArray = new int[quizzes];
    double* studentAverage = new double[students];
    string studentName = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < students; i++)
    { 
        cout << "Enter the students name: ";
        getline(cin, studentName);
        studentArray[i] = studentName;
        cout << studentName;

        for(int j = 0; j < quizzes; j++)
        {
            cout << "Enter quiz " << j+1 << ":";
            cin >> quizArray[j];
        }
        studentAverage[i] = calculateAvergage(quizArray,quizzes);
        cout << studentArray[i];
        cout << studentName;
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Student              Quiz Average" << endl << endl;
    cout << "---------------------------------" << endl << endl;


    for(int i = 0; i < students; i++)
    {
        cout << studentArray[i];
        cout << setw(10) << studentAverage[i] << endl << endl;
    }   
}
int getStudents(int students)
{
    cout << "How many students?  ";
    cin >> students;
    cout << endl;
    if(students > 50)
    {
        cout << "Invalid number of students, enter a number less than 50: ";
        cin >> students;
        cout << endl;
    }
    return students;
}
int getQuizzes(int quizzes)
{
    cout << "How many quizzes?  ";
    cin >> quizzes;
    cout << endl;
    if(quizzes > 10)
    {
        cout << "Invalid number of quizzes, enter a number less than 10: ";
        cin >> quizzes;
        cout << endl;
    }
    return quizzes;
}
double calculateAvergage(int quiz_array[],int num_quizzes)
{
    double average = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < num_quizzes; i++)
    {
        average = quiz_array[i] + average;
    }
    average = (average/num_quizzes);
    return average;
}
```

Comment: `cin` is probably in a failed state, **post a complete example**.

Comment: whole program posted as requested

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ getline method not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19257205/c-getline-method-not-working)

Comment: `getStudents(students);` is undefined behaviour, you haven't initialized `students`. Same for `quizzes`. You don't even need to pass arguments to those functions.

Comment: initialize them within the function? i just initialized them in main to 0 and im having the same issue

Comment: @user3558697 It's not initialization, it's assignment. But you're passing `students` as a parameter when it's uninitialized.

Comment: @user3558697 it's not the actual root cause of your issue, but until you squash undefined behaviour your program is worthless.

Comment: @user657267 i prototyped the functions above main if that's what you mean they're both correct. if thats not what you mean i'm not sure i understand what you're saying.

Comment: Parameters are used to send data to functions. getStudents doesn't use the value sent in the students parameter. It should be a local variable.

Comment: Why is students hardset to 50 but quizes dynamically allocated, but arbitrarily hardset to max 10? Use vectors and resize them according to input value.

Comment: You're mixing line-based input with `>>`, if you don't make sure you consume leftover end of line characters you're going to have a bad time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading single values from a stream like this

```
cin >> quizzes;
```

does not consume the trailing end of line character (or any other invalid characters that were left over after attempting to read `quizzes`), so the next call to `getline` will continue reading from the same line of input (usually you would expect the line to be empty after reading `quizzes`, so `getline` ends up reading nothing).

Your program should work if use the following after reading `quizzes`:

```
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

or you can just simply read `studentName` in the same way as the other values

```
std::cin >> studentName;
```

As with all calls to `operator>>` this strips all leading whitespace including newlines.